# cauchy sequence problems

Tags: real-analysis

Let $x_n$ be a Cauchy sequence. Suppose that for every $\varepsilon > 0$ there is some $N > 1/\varepsilon$ such that $\mathopen|x_N \mathclose| < \varepsilon$. Prove that $\displaystyle \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}x_n = 0$.

Comment: Do Cauchy sequences converge?

Answer (score 0):

Well, actually your question has a little flaw of logic. First, you did not mention the space in which the sequence is considered. If we set $X=(0,1)$ and $x_n=\frac{1}{n}$ then indeed the sequence $\{\frac{1}{n}\}_{n\in\Bbb N}$ is Cauchy sequence but $\displaystyle \lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{n}$ does not exists in $X$.

On the other hand, if we consider the set $X=[0,1]$ then the above sequence is Cauchy sequence and converges to zero. Note: In a **complete** metric space a sequence is Cauchy iff it is convergent.

P.S.: The thing you assumed by saying "Suppose that for every ... " is the condition for convergence of a sequence to zero. Recall that a  sequence $\{x_n\}_{n\in\Bbb N}$ is said to converge to a limit $l$ is that for every $\epsilon>0$ there is a $N\in\Bbb N$ s.t. $$|x_n-l|<\epsilon,\forall n\ge N.$$

Here $l=0$ reduces to your problem.